# How to implement a parallel logical or with early termination in Clojure

Tags: clojure, parallel-processing, functional-programming, logic, terminate

I would like to define a predicate that, taking as input some predicates
with corresponding inputs (they could be given as a lazy sequence of calls),
runs them in parallel and computes the logical or of the results,
in such a way that, the moment a predicate call terminates returning `true`,
the whole computation also terminates (returning `true`).

Apart from offering time optimization, this would also help avoiding
non-termination in some cases (some predicate calls may not terminate).
Actually, interpreting non-termination as a third `undefined` value,
this predicate simulates the or operation in [Kleene's K3 logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic#Logics)
(the join in the initial centered [Kleene algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan_algebra#Kleene_algebra)).

Something similar is presented [here](http://www.mathematik.uni-marburg.de/~lobachev/papers/lobachev-flops12.pdf) for the Haskell family.
Is there any (preferably simple) way to do this in Clojure?

**EDIT**: I decided to add some clarifications after reading the comments.

(a) First of all, what happens after the thread pool gets exhausted is of less importance. I think creating a thread pool large enough for our needs is a reasonable convention.

(b) The most crucial requirement is that the predicate calls start running in parallel and, once a predicate call terminates returning `true`, all the other threads running get interrupted. The intended behavior is that:

- if there is a predicate call returning `true`: the parallel or returns `true`
- else if there is a predicate call that does not terminate: the parallel or does not terminate
- else: the parallel or returns `false`

In other words, it behaves like the join in the 3-element lattice given by `false`<`undefined`<`true`, with `undefined` representing non-termination.

(c) The parallel or should be able to take as input many predicates and many predicate-inputs (each one corresponding to a predicate). But it would be even better if it took as input a lazy sequence. Then, naming the parallel or `pany` (for "parallel any"), we could have calls like the following:

- `(pany (map (comp eval list) predicates inputs))`
- `(pany (map (comp eval list) predicates (repeat input)))`
- `(pany (map (comp eval list) (repeat predicate) inputs))` which is equivalent to `(pany (map predicate (unchunk inputs)))`

As a final remark, I think that it is quite natural to ask for things like `pany`, a dual `pall` or a mechanism for building such early-terminating parallel reductions to be easily implementable or even built-in in a parallelism-oriented language like Clojure.

Comment: After a few tries, I ended up with [this](https://gist.github.com/carcigenicate/f19a47f20c0f8cb670307e18ea4c0d03). It will run the predicate checks in a Java thread pool of adjustable size, and will skip further checks as soon as it finds a result. The problem is, and the reason I'm not posting an answer, is this code will hang indefinitely if there is no true result found since the promise will never be delivered, so deref'ing the promise will block forever. I'm unable to find a solution, but thought I'd post what I had in case it can be built on.

Comment: I guess the problem is if the first n results fail to terminate, where n is the size of your threadpool, then we will never return. Think that it needs interruptible operations, maybe.

Comment: Do you want checks that are currently running to be cancelled once a result is found, or do you just want to prevent new checks from starting? If the latter, see my [new version of `check-in-par`](https://gist.github.com/carcigenicate/2a09ac89e65efa751027576f8ee37b3b). I fixed the previous problem with some inspiration from `promise`. Unfortunately, it requires knowing the length of the predicate lists. I don't see how you could avoid that though. You have to somehow know when the checks are finished to report failure.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I think any solution will involve doing something morally equivalent to counting the input. What worries me more is: what if there are N (here 4) or more tasks which never complete? Your threadpool fills up with stuck threads. It seems to me like Fork/Join and CompletableFuture may help here, but I'm not sure: they probably don't appreciate a worker thread just crawling into a hole.

Comment: @amalloy You could switch to using `submit` from `execute` and timeout the tasks if you had a reasonable upper limit for execution time (I think the returned Futures allow that). You could also switch from a fixed thread pool to one that's a little more dynamic like one returned by `newCachedThreadPool`. If there's the possibility that tasks won't complete ever though, adding a timeout is the only option I can see since an expanded pool will just allow more infinite jobs to sit in the pool at once.

Comment: Or switching to ExecutorService's `invokeAny` method. It seems like it times out. I've never used it before though.

Comment: Did anyone read the paper? Reimplementing all the various skeletons in Clojure is out of scope for a StackOverflow answer, and my consulting rates are unreasonable, however I reckon I can make a stab at answering this in terms of parallel reductions if I get a free hour. We’ll see:-)

Comment: @Carcigenicate: Lots of thanks for the effort you've put into this! See my edit for clarifications.

Comment: @pete23: I didn't ask anyone to transfer to Clojure everything mentioned in this paper! I just wondered if this type of parallel reduction can be implemented in a simple way and gave the paper as a reference to something similar, as it was my most relevant search result. Could this maybe be proposed as a future addition to Clojure (if it is difficult to implement and as natural as I think it is)?

Comment: I think that by moving the thread pool exhaustion out of scope you are specifying a toy. Any implementation should deal with the first n computations not terminating, where n > threads.

Answer (score 1):

I will define our predicates in terms of a reducing function. Practically, we could reimplement all of the Clojure iteration functions to support this parallel operation, but I'll just use reduce as an example.

I'll define a computation function. I'll just use the same one, but nothing stopping you from having many. The function is "true" if it accumulates 1000.

```
(defn computor [acc val]
        (let [new (+' acc val)] (if (> new 1000) (reduced new) new)))

(reduce computor 0 (range))
;; =>
1035

(reduce computor 0 (range Long/MIN_VALUE 0))
;; =>
;; ...this is a proxy for a non-returning computation

;; wrap these up in a form suitable for application of reduction
(def predicates [[computor 0 (range)] 
                 [computor 0 (range Long/MIN_VALUE 0)]])
```

Now let's get to the meat of this. I want to take a step in each computation, and if one of the computations completes, I want to return it. In actual fact one step at a time using pmap is very slow - the units of work are too small to be worth threading. Here I've changed things to do 1000 iterations of each unit of work before moving on. You'd probably tune this based on your workload and the cost of a step.

```
(defn p-or-reducer* [reductions]
        (let [splits (map #(split-at 1000 %) reductions) ;; do at least 1000 iterations per cycle
              complete (some #(if (empty? (second %)) (last (first %))) splits)]
          (or complete (recur (map second splits)))))
```

I then wrap this in a driver.

```
(defn p-or [s]
  (p-or-reducer* (map #(apply reductions %) s)))

(p-or predicates)
;; =>
1035
```

Where to insert the CPU parallelism? s/map/pmap/ in p-or-reducer* should do it. I suggest just parallelising the first operation, as this will drive the reducing sequences to compute.

```
(defn p-or-reducer* [reductions]
        (let [splits (pmap #(split-at 1000 %) reductions) ;; do at least 1000 iterations per cycle
              complete (some #(if (empty? (second %)) (last (first %))) splits)]
          (or complete (recur (map second splits)))))

(def parallelism-tester (conj (vec (repeat 40000 [computor 0 (range Long/MIN_VALUE 0)]))
                             [computor 0 (range)]))

(p-or parallelism-tester) ;; terminates even though the first 40K predicates will not
```

It's extremely hard to define a performant generic version of this. Without knowing the cost per iteration an efficient parallelism strategy is hard to derive - if one iteration take 10s then we'd probably take a single step at a time. If it takes 100ns then we need to take many steps at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Will you consider adopting `core.async` to handle parallel tasks with `async/go` or `async/thread`, and early return with `async/alts!`?

For example, to turn the core `or` function from serial into parallel.  We can create a macro (I called it `por`) to wrap the input functions (or predicates) into `async/thread` and then do a socket select `async/alts!` on top of them:

```clj
(defmacro por [& fns]
  `(let [[v# c#] (async/alts!!
                  [~@(for [f fns]
                       (list `async/thread f))])]
     v#))

(time
 (por (do (println "running a") (Thread/sleep 30) :a)
      (do (println "running b") (Thread/sleep 20) :b)
      (do (println "running c") (Thread/sleep 10) :c)))
;; running a
;; running b
;; running c
;; "Elapsed time: 11.919169 msecs"
;; => :c
```

In comparison with the original `or` (which run in serial):

```clj
(time
 (or (do (println "running a") (Thread/sleep 30) :a)
     (do (println "running b") (Thread/sleep 20) :b)
     (do (println "running c") (Thread/sleep 10) :c)))
;; running a
;; => :a
;; "Elapsed time: 31.642506 msecs"
```

Comment: What happens in the case where n predicates don’t halt, where n is higher than the core.async threadpool?

Comment: One way to handle this is to start the parallel or-clause with a function which returns default answer after timeout, then we can be sure caller will always get an answer.  Handling run-away/long-running task would require certain knowledge on the task itself (i.e. how to cancel the task).  In the case of `go` block task which takes input from `go` channel, I will simply use another channel as a control to signal early termination (using `alts!`).

Comment: Even if caller gets an answer, the worker threads will still beaver away!

Comment: If you decompose the function into a go block, where the iterator can receive a “step” message or a “terminate” message then I think you’re there. Key is to externalise loop control so termination is in the hand of the coordinator.